# How does (GET "/" request (str request)) work in compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

I am wondering what magic is occurring for this code from  https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Destructuring-Syntax

**(GET "/" request
  (str request))**

I would expect it to look something like

**(GET "/" [request]
  (str request))**

Specifically, how is the request bound to the second argument?

Is the request always bound to the second argument?

What differentiates request vs [request]?

I have changed my code to see what happens in each of these scenarios, just trying to understand the reason and make sure I don't make and wrong assumptions about the second arg being bound to the request.

Thanks
-jv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request map is always bound to the second argument passed to the route macros. If you bind it as map, it will be destructored via regular Clojure [Map binding destructoring.](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20(Destructuring)-Map%20binding%20destructuring) If you bind it as a vector, Compojures macro looks the symbols up as equally named keys in the `:params` map of the request map. The latter is Compojure specific and explained in the link you provided with the question.

The binding takes place by the `GET` macro transforming the forms you pass to it into sourcecode of a request handler function with the desired lookups in scope.

The first example binds `request` to the entire request map.

The second example binds `request` to the value of key `:request` of the map of key `:params` of the request map.